# Codeigniter not showing error pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not able to show error pages which are in built on the CI framework.

As per their documentation I have used

`show_error('message' [, int $status_code= 500 ] );`

Do I have to load any libraries for showing error pages?

Please help.

Comment: want to create 404 page ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Not 404 errors.But wanted to show custom errors.So i tried with the one codeigniter documentation has,but its not working out

Comment: which type of custom errors?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Im creating an API right now.Suppose if in the api request,the apikey is invalid/not authorized,i wanted to show a custom error page saying 'Error code :10 invalid API' or something of this sort.Also this is not  rest API.I want to show a standard error template with an error code and message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to use session flash message (temporary session data)

if invalid api id create a view and redirect this view with error message:-

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'invalid api key');
redirect('viewname', 'refresh');
```

On view show error message :-

```
$this->session->flashdata('error_message');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.But what does this show_error('message' [, int $status_code= 500 ] ); do?

Comment: it's not for custom error messages it's for page not found, server errors

Comment: Thanks.Istead of redirect('viewname', 'refresh'); , can I use $this->load->view(''); ?? or is it there anything different in using this?

Comment: on load view no need to flash you can send error in data array

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in application/core/ and extends the system exception class

```
<?php
// application/core/MY_Exceptions.php
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function show_404()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->output->set_status_header('404'); 
        $CI->load->view('error_page');
        echo $CI->output->get_output();
        exit;
    }
}
```

create a error page and pass the message you want.